# LiFePO4 battery capacity, influence of temperature

Tags: battery-chemistry, lifepo4

The main question is, if Lithium Iron Phosphate batteries are regaining capacity when heated up.

**Assume:**

- a nominal 3000mAh 3.2V cell @ 25°C
- capacity at -20°C taken from datasheet is 1500mAh
- battery is fully charged at 25°C and then cooled down to -20°C in a passive state
- the battery which is at -20°C is heated up through energy taken from the same battery
- the capacity used to heat the battery is 750mAh, so if the battery would still be at -20° the remaining charge is 750mAh

Since the battery is back at 25°C after heating, what capacity remains? 50% of 3000mAh or 3000mAh - 750mAh = 2250mAh?